# how to get 30 min back instance object (Instance.now() -30 min)

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, instant

```
private Instant submissionDate = Instant.now();


void scheduleResult() {
    if(submissionDate befor 30 min)
            execute;
}
```

how to perform a scheduler task if submisisionDate is older than 30 min.

Comment: Please search before asking a find a good answer even faster. I found this eassily: [java.time.Instant.minus() Method Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javatime/javatime_instant_minus.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Instant#minus(30, ChronoUnit.MINUTES)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#minus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-)

```
Instant submissionDate = ...

Instant now = Instant.now(); 
Instant thirtyMinutesBeforeNow = now.minus(30, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

if (submissionDate.isBefore(thirtyMinutesBeforeNow)) {

}
```

or [`Instant#minusSeconds(1800)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#minusSeconds-long-)

```
Instant submissionDate = ...

Instant now = Instant.now(); 
Instant thirtyMinutesBeforeNow = now.minusSeconds(1800);

if (submissionDate.isBefore(thirtyMinutesBeforeNow)) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initalize a 30 minute in the past date:

```
LocalDateTime halfHourInPast = LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(30);
```

and use it to compare your date:

```
LocalDateTime submissionDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(submissionDateInstant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
if(submissionDate.isBefore(halfHourInPast)){
   //schedule
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( submissionDate.isBefore(Instant.now().minus(30, ChronoUnit.MINUTES))){
//                      run
}
```

Comment: This is one of the two preferred ways. The other is `Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofMinutes(30))`. Take the one you like best.